# Calling a python script in Cakephp

Tags: php, python, cakephp, passthru

I wrote  a service class called search_categorization_service.php. Now I am making a call to python scrpt in this class

```
class SearchCategorizationService
{
    function searcher($query)
    {
    $tmp=passthru("python serverscript1.py $query");
    ob_start();
    $out=ob_get_contents(); 
    echo print_r($out,true);
    }
}
```

but i dont get any output on the browser. i tried returning it to a controller class and printing the output but it just wont work.any help wud be appreciated. is it an issue with cakephp? because the same application works fine in normal php.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `ob_start()` above `$tmp=passthru("python serverscript1.py $query");`. It appears nothing is being output after the output buffer is started.

```
<?php
class SearchCategorizationService
{
    function searcher($query)
    {
    ob_start();
    $tmp=passthru("python serverscript1.py $query");
    $out=ob_get_contents(); 
    echo print_r($out,true);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry tried.. it didnt work..the same code i ran with normal php ran normally and fetched result.

Comment: Do you know if `ob_get_contents` is returning `FALSE`?

Comment: Also, is the python script in PYTHONPATH?

Comment: i am able to execute the same python script from the services directory where the script is stored. and for a given query it returns result on the terminal but no output for the browser